# Do frequent & small commits help git merge?

Tags: git, merge

We use git for our projects. Pretty standard workflow with feature branches merged back into master. Sadly changes in feature branches tend to be bigger (a lot of lines changed) than one would prefer - this causes occasional conflicts.

Q1: Does frequent committing (lots of small changes committed) help with automatic resolution of conflicts performed by git-merge? Does answer change if using external tool for merging (eg. kdiff3)?

Theory is that if git-merge can see small incremental changes in log it has more info to resolve conflicts. On the other hand it is conceivable that it will actually see more conflicts that would be "out of date" in final merge. So:

Q2: Does git even use information about commit history when performing merge?

Q3: Does answer to either Q1,Q2 change if we use rebase instead of merge?

I know that at least rebase gets awful if commit history is long and conflict occures early on.

Comment: Largely merges are made easier because one is encouraged to do lots of little merges rather than a few huge ones. The difficulty of a merge scales horribly with the amount of change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the friction which would occur during a merge comes from the diff between the HEAD of the two branches which are involved in the merge.  That is, it does not matter how many commits there are between the point where these two branches originated, but rather just on how different the code is in each file, between both branches.

Rebasing, on the other hand, might be another story.  The nature of rebasing involves replaying all the distinct commits on one branch against a new base, which incorporates the commits from the other branch.  If you had, say, 10 commits to replay, and the changes in each commit were fairly small, then you might have an easy time resolving each conflict.  This could contrast doing the same via merge, where there could be one large big ugly set of merge conflicts.  But, rebasing may also come with a price.  Because you might have to replay many commits, you also might have to fix merge conflicts in each commit.  This can become untenable if you have hundreds of commits.  And in that case, most people would rather just do a single merge.

In general, a good strategy for making commits is that you should commit when you have finished some logically sensible portion of your coding task.  One of the one hand, making too frequent commits can lead to an ugly branch, and on the other hand, committing too infrequently can lead to problems if you ever have to revert.  This is so because then it becomes difficult to tease apart steps you have taken.

Answer (score 2):

> Does answer change if using external tool for merging (eg. kdiff3)?

Answering this part of the question: There is [git imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge), which *does* use the complete commit history to resolve merge conflicts, in order to at least make manual conflict resolution a lot easier.

This is not a mergetool like kdiff3, but rather a script that performs a merge (or rebase) incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: I think this question refers to merging feature branches into master. This does not make any difference whether you have many atomic commits or bigger ones that are less semantically structured. The advantage you gain from atomic commits is within CI and you see which changes introduce failures of tests.

Q2: No

Q3: What Tim Biegeleisen said. I also advise you to read Atlassians great guide on [Merging vs. Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)